# Branches of $\frac{1}{1-\cos (z\sqrt z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering why should $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\cos (z\sqrt z)}$ be a monodromic function. By the properties of the complex square root one has:

$z \sqrt z=z z^{1/2}=z^{3/2}:=e^{3/2 \ln_{\mathbb{C}}(z)}=|z|^{3/2}e^{3/2 i\arg z}e^{3 k \pi i}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $|k|$ is even: $z \sqrt z = |z|^{3/2}e^{3/2 i\arg z}$, otherwise $z \sqrt z =-|z|^{3/2}e^{3/2 i\arg z}$. So I've ended up with two branches and $f$ is not monodromic.

Have I committed a mistake?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that $\cos$ is an even function. Its power series at zero has only even-degree terms, so if we substitute $z\sqrt{z}$ there, we get a new series with only degrees divisible by $3$. Therefore $\cos(z\sqrt{z})$ is an entire function, and $\frac1{1-\cos(z\sqrt{z})}$ is meromorphic without branches on the whole plane.

Comment: (+1) This is a point not often discussed in a course in complex analysis, but is very useful to the applied mathematician, physicist, engineer, etc.  And without even discussing the power series of the cosine we see that $\cos(f(z))=\frac12(e^{if(z)}+e^{-if(z)})$ is even in $f(z)$.